# Installing a Newer Package than what's in RHEL's Repositories

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel6, repository

What's the best way in RHEL to install a newer version of a package than what's in the repositories?

In Ubuntu I can just add the repo for a newer version of Ubuntu, install the package with apt, and then disable the newer repo, but with RHEL and having to register the system with RHN, I don't see a way to do this.  Is there some other way that would be more appropriate?

In particular, I'm trying to get a newer version of gcc-gfortran installed.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Actually the technique you describe for Ubuntu is dangerous and very often results in broken systems. Packages built for a newer distribution are not guaranteed to work on an older distribution, very often do not work reliably or at all, and often break the system in unforeseen ways.

Comment: As for gfortran, just how new does it need to be? RHEL 7 already has version 4.8.2, which should be fine for virtually anything not involving development of the compiler itself...

Comment: Yeah, I'm always nervous using that approach, but I've had to do it on a couple of occasions and it's yet to cause me any issues.

Comment: As for version, 4.8.2 would be new enough, but my system is running RHEL 6, so it's only at 4.4.7.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options for getting a newer version of gcc than the one shipped with RHEL 6, your current Linux distribution.

1. Upgrade to RHEL 7, which shipped with gcc 4.8.2.
2. Use the [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/), a software collection which supplies gcc 4.9.1 and updated versions of related tools, on either RHEL 6 or RHEL 7. This software collection is available with [most RHEL subscriptions](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/472793), but is in a separate subscription channel from Red Hat Software Collections.